Fabricjs Textbox 'selectable' and 'hasControls' set to false after loadFromJSON
I'm implementing undo functionality in my Fabric.js project using JSON.stringify to save the canvas state and loadFromJSON to restore it. However, after restoring the canvas from JSON, only textboxes have their selectable and hasControls properties automatically set to false. This causes them to become non-interactive.
Below is my implementation for saving the state of the canvas:
const saveHistory = useCallback(() => {
    if (!canvas) return;

    const state = JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON(['selectable', 'hasControls', 'evented', 'hoverCursor', 'name']));
    setHistoryUndo((prevState) => {
        let historyUndoClone = [...prevState];
        if (historyUndoClone.length === HISTORY_LIMIT) {
            historyUndoClone.shift();
        }
        return [...historyUndoClone, state];
    });
    setHistoryRedo([]);
}, [canvas, setHistoryRedo, setHistoryUndo]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (canvas) {
        // Other event listeners...
        canvas.on('object:modified', (event) => {
            saveHistory();
        });

        canvas.on('text:changed', (event) => {
            saveHistory();
        });
    }
    return () => {
        if (canvas) {
            canvas.off();
        }
    };
}, [canvas, activeTool, setActiveTool, setExpanded, setSelectedObjects, historyRedo, historyUndo, saveHistory]);


I used text:changed to watch for text edit. I also included selectable, hasControls in the toObject method.
Below is the logic for undo:
if (historyUndo.length > 1) {
    let historyUndoClone = [...historyUndo];
    const previousState = historyUndoClone.pop();
    setHistoryUndo(historyUndoClone);

    if (previousState) { 
        const lastState = historyUndoClone[historyUndoClone.length - 1]; 
        canvas.loadFromJSON(lastState, () => {
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
    }
}


Currently, I don't know what caused this. So my current workaround is  getting all textboxes after loading the canvas from json and manually set their selectable and hasControls to true:
canvas.loadFromJSON(lastState, () => {
    const newObjects = canvas.getObjects();
    
    newObjects.forEach(object => {
        if (object.type === 'textbox') {
            object.set({
                selectable: true,
                hasControls: true,
            });
        }
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
});


The project also have some Zustand store and loadFromJSON also alter their values as well. I don't know if these problems is because  I implement them or it is a fabricjs bug.
